# Can libgdx be used to create not game app?

Tags: libgdx, multiplatform

I want to create an app with a drawing editor like Paint. I want to use libgdx for two reasons:

1. The code must be cross-platform.
2. I prefer to use java as a programming language because it is the language I know best and the only one with which I can use sockets.

I know it is possible to create a non-game app in libgdx, I want to know if it is convenient, if there are any downsides;for example, any application in libgdx has a main class like this:

```
@Override

public void create () {

}

@Override

public void render () {

}
```

The render method is repeated over and over again, this takes a lot of resources for the device running the application compared to an app not written in libgdx (so without this create / render methods setting, and therefore without a method that is repeated  continuously)?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-and-Non-Continuous-Rendering

Comment: thanks for the answer, so if I set non-continuous rendering I shouldn't waste resources anymore?